# Chrome beforeunload Event and history API

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, onbeforeunload, html5-history

I have thus code to store the scroll position and height of a responsive page with a drawer menu.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function (e) {
                if (window.history && window.history.replaceState) {
                    var $formContainer = $('#Form1'),
                        $drawerContent = $('#drawer-content'),
                        pageState = {
                            page: window.location.href,
                            formContainerHeight: $formContainer.height(),
                            drawerContentScrollTop: $drawerContent.scrollTop()
                        };
                    console.log(pageState, e.type)
                    window.history.replaceState(pageState, window.document.title);
                }
            });
```

On page load I console.log the window.history.state to ensure page size when going back / forward in history.

I get the expected values in IE10+, FireFox and Opera, but chrome seems to log the values from the page in history +1.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't Hack so hard, and messing with the title
Javascript provides a set of nice methods to handle prev/next while actually staying on the same page:
Namely location.hash ( [Fragment Identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) ).
Use them instead: www.whatever/index#125,615 where x,y are your values